# Centre Content in DIV vertically in bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to centre some text within a DIV vertically. However, I'm using Bootstrap and none of the conventional methods seem to work because it's within a column. Here's what I've got so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="innercontent">
        <h2 class="text-center">Last Hope: The Halo Machinima</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.innercontent {
    display:block
    margin:auto 0;
}
```

The `col-sm-6` doesn't have a set height and nor does the inner because they will vary on multiple uses. The CSS is what I assumed would work but doesn't.
The effect I kinda want you can see on the live dev site here: http://dev.infiniteideamedia.com/machinima/lasthope.php but it's not perfectly centred using a less than adequate method.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Have you used Flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you center anything inside `div` which has dynamic height

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="innercontent">
         <h2 class="text-center">Last Hope: The Halo Machinima</h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

David Walsh has written a good [article on centering](http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center). Have a look at it.
Run below snippet

```css
.innercontent {
 height:400px;
 background:#777; 
padding-top:20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="innercontent">
    <h2 class="text-center">Last Hope: The Halo Machinima</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i know the reason why it is voted down? His sample page wanted his text to be like this

Comment: Doesn't provide a solution to dynamic height. The OP clearly said **The col-sm-6 doesn't have a set height and nor does the inner because they will vary on multiple uses.**

Comment: i set the height for reference purpose, once the content is inserted, height can be set to auto and still percent based padding will work the you want.

Comment: And your text isn't exactly vertically center aligned as well.